# Export instance variable as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, export

Ruby on Rails 3

I am exporting a database table in xml format. I am trying to get a string based on the user_id of a table.

So here I am getting all surveys which has a user_id. Then I am getting the region attribute from another table based on the user_id which is on both tables.

It seems to work fine, but I get this

```
#<Reseller:0x00000003596a98>
```

Instead of the string, "North America"

Here is my xls loop"

```
<% @all_surveys.each do |survey| %>
  <% @id = survey.user_id %>
  <% @region = Reseller.find(@id) %>
  <Row>        
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= survey.id %></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= survey.user_id %></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= @region %></Data></Cell>
  </Row>
<% end %>
```

I tried

```
instance_variable_get("@#{region}")
```

But am finding documentation hard to find. Thank you,

Comment: Maybe I should be doing this in the controller with appending the region attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a `Reseller` have a region?

`Reseller.find(@id)` will return a `Reseller` object but you need to access the region attribute on that object (i.e. `Reseller.find(@id).region` if `region` is an attribute).

Comment: Reseller has company_region as an attribute

Comment: try `Reseller.find(@id).company_region` instead of `Reseller.find(@id)`